# Is it possible to generate a list of `EditText` pairs that automatically retain their state?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-view

I am running into a very frustrating series of problems. I would like a definitive solution; thus, I will award bounty for this question.

### Requirements

1. Generate a list of pairs of `EditText` views that automatically retain their values on orientation change (screen rotation).
2. The number of `EditText` pairs is determined at runtime.

### Failing method: Use a `ListView`

Use a `ListView` that has an `ArrayAdapter`. The array adapter uses a layout to generate each pair of `TextView` views. The XML for a `ListView` item might appear as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_first"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `ArrayAdapter` would simply inflate the layout for each view.

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_pair, parent, false);
```

The values entered into the `EditText` are not retained on orientation change. Since the `EditText` views are instantiated through the `ArrayAdapter`, the Android runtime has no way of automatically pre-populating the `EditText` views with their last state before rotation. This means we must save/restore user-input manually -- failing requirement #1.

### Failing method: Use a `TableLayout` and `TableRow`s

Instead of using a `ListView`, we can inflate one `TableRow` layout for each `EditText` pair and attach it to the `TableLayout`. Since we only know the number of pairs at runtime (per requirement #2) we must instantiate the layout programmatically. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; ++i)
{
  TableRow row = (TableRow) View.inflate(this, R.layout.tablerow_pair, null);
  table.addView(row);
}
```

This also fails to retain state on orientation change. Each pair of `EditText` views has the same `Id`s as all other `EditText` pairs in the `ListView`. This happens because we instantiate the same layout for each item in the list; thus, they all have the same `Id`s. On rotation, Android will give every pair of `EditText` values the same values since they share the same `Id`.

### Recapitulation

So, is there a way to create a list of `EditText` pairs that retain their state automatically upon orientation change? It seems like there must be a way, yet researching this question is difficult because it's a fairly specialized use case. I would be glad to reward some bounty for somebody who can give me a nice explanation of this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use `setId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) with your `EditText` widgets, whether you create those widgets via their constructors or via layout inflation (per your second strategy). Use [`generateViewId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29) to get distinct view IDs.

Comment: Would there be any way to meet these requirements with the `ListView` approach?

Comment: Also it's API level 16 on generateViewId() which makes it virtually useless.

Comment: @mindandsky: "Would there be any way to meet these requirements with the ListView approach?" -- not readily, mostly because focusable widgets and `ListView` don't get alone all that well. "Also it's API level 16 on generateViewId() which makes it virtually useless" -- you are welcome to define a bunch of view IDs as ID resources and use those, then.